# C# client/server chat app using simpletcp NuGet package

Tags: c#

this is my first post and I'm desperate for an answer. I'm trying to create a chat application as a self study project but I've hit a dead end. I used the simpletcp NuGet package on Visual Studio 2015 to create this, now my code has been obfuscated a bit so I'll attempt to make everything as clear as possible. My issue is that if I open multiple clients, the server receives everything correctly but the clients only see their own text. I'm not sure how to send a string from the server back to all the chat clients. Any help would be appreciated.

```
namespace ChattyCathy_v0._2_Client
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    SimpleTcpClient client;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        client = new SimpleTcpClient();
        client.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
        client.DataReceived += Client_DataReceived;

    }

    private void Client_DataReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
    {
        txtStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
        {
            client.DataReceived += Client_DataReceived;
            listBox1.Items.Add(e.MessageString);
            e.ReplyLine(string.Format("You said: {0}", e.MessageString));
            e.ReplyLine(string.Format("\n" + loginName + " said: {0}", e.MessageString));

        });
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        client = new SimpleTcpClient().Connect(textBox1.Text, Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text));
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String loginName = "Zack";
        listBox1.Items.Add("\nYou said: " + textBox3.Text);
        client.WriteLineAndGetReply(loginName + " said: " + textBox3.Text, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));


    }
}
```

}

And here is the server code:

```
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    SimpleTcpServer server;
    private String loginName;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        server = new SimpleTcpServer();
        server.Delimiter = 0x13;
        server.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
        server.DataReceived += Server_DataReceived;

    }

    private void Server_DataReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
    {
        txtStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(e.MessageString +"\n");
            e.ReplyLine(string.Format("\n" + loginName + " said: {0}", e.MessageString));

        });

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (server.IsStarted)
        {
            server.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add( "Server Starting...");
        System.Net.IPAddress ip = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(txtHost.Text);
        server.Start(ip, Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you found out your answer, but if you use `server.BroadcastLine("your msg here")`  or `sever.Broadcast("your msg here")`. 
This command will send it to all connected clients.